# How to show simple product name of a configurable product on Checkout Payment page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, configurable-product, mini-cart, simple-product

I want to show a Simple product with a Configurable product name on ( Mini-cart, Cart page, and checkout page ).
I have successfully achieved to show the name on Mini-cart and Cart page but on the Checkout page I have created a module that is successfully showing the Name on the shipping page but it doesn't show on the Payment page can anyone have any idea why it is not showing there.

I have shown the value by

```
<?php
namespace Hl\Checkoutname\Plugin;
class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
 public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider 
$subject, array $result)
   {
 $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();          

 for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

  $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
  $quoteNext = ($quoteId + 1);

  $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteNext);
  $simpleProName = $quote->getName();
  $simpleProType = $quote->getProductId();

  $items[$i]['childname'] = $simpleProName;
  $items[$i]['producttype'] = $simpleProType;
}
 $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
 return $result;
 }
}
```

My di.xml file path: app/code/Hl/Checkoutname/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"> 
 <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Hl\Checkoutname\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
 </type>
  <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository">
    <plugin name="Hl_Checkoutname_Plugin_Frontend_Magento_Catalog_Model_Layer" type="Hl\Checkoutname\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\CartTotalRepository" sortOrder="15" disabled="false"/>
  </type>
 </config>
```

My Plugin file path : app/code/Hl/Checkoutname/Plugin/Frontend/Magento/Catalog/Model/Layer/CartTotalRepository.php

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace Hl\Checkoutname\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;

    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

    class CartTotalRepository
    {
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository $subject,
        $result,
        $cartId
    ) {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface) {
            $items = $result->getItems();
            $resultItems = [];
            foreach ($items as $eachItem) {
                $name = $eachItem->getName();
                $eachItem->setName($name);
                // Do your code
                $resultItems['childname'] = $eachItem;
            }
            $result->setItems($resultItems);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    }
```

As in my app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/item/details.html I have used

```
 <strong class="product-item-childname" data-bind="html: $parent.childname"></strong>
```

to show the name so that's why I have returned the value with this but still not getting a name.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an **after** plugin on `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository:get`  as the payment step details coming from the rest api.

**di.xml for declare the plugin**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository">
        <plugin name="StackExchanges_Magento_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_Cart_CartTotalRepository" type="StackExchanges\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository" sortOrder="15" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**and Plugin class**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchanges\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class CartTotalRepository
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository $subject,
        $result,
        $cartId
    ) {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface) {
            $items = $result->getItems();
            $resultItems = [];
            foreach ($items as $eachItem) {
                $name = $eachItem->getName();
                //$eachItem->setName($name . ' ' . __METHOD__);
                // Do your code
                $resultItems[] = $eachItem;
            }
            $result->setItems($resultItems);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    private function getName($eachItem)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @amit
Can you please explain how to achieve as it is new thing to me like how to extend it using di.xml or using any other file.

Comment: For plugin check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: i use  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#after-methods

Comment: Thanks @amit i have updated the files in question with its paths can you please check and tell me what is wrong with it as my product name is still not there.

Comment: sorry, mistake.Provided wrong di.xml.Please check updated di.xml

Comment: Thanks for your correction ,
I have updated my di.xml but still not getting name i have updated my files and screenshot please check.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get product ID like it always give me error
Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item::getId()

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Looking for a solution like this